# Subscripts - Why do I see the error "only assignments to symbols are allowed" when using a Module and not otherwise?

Tags: variable-definitions, scoping

When I type

```
Remove["Global`*"]
foo[] := Module[{Subscript[a, 1] = "x"}, 0]; 
foo[]
```

I get the expected error "only assignments to symbols are allowed". I understand the error.

[image]

But why I do not get the same error when I type the same assignment in the notebook?

```
Remove["Global`*"]
Subscript[a, 1] = "x"
```

No error and no beep.

[image]

What is the difference? I'm using version 8.04 on Windows.

---

### Update

The non-localized trick shown by Szabolcs answer worked for me on a demo. Here is a screen shot of the result. What I was trying to do is to typeset some information about a solver, some matrix equation, and I thought why not take advantage of `MatrixForm` and `Grid`'s nice way of typesetting things, and display the information right there in the demo screen as an option? This is easier than putting it in the text section below where it can hard to get to as I have so many such things.

Here is an example of the code and the result. You can see I did not localized these symbols in the module which builds this expression. I just started trying this idea, but so far I am happy that it worked. This below is only an example, not cleaned up, just wanted to see if the demo will work.

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is because only symbols can be *localized* by `Module`.   It is not about assignment, but localization.

`Subscript[a, 1]` is not a symbol, but a compound expression, so:

```
Module[{Subscript[a, 1] = "x"}, 0] (* <-- not allowed *)

Module[{}, Subscript[a, 1] = "x"]  (* <-- allowed but not localized *)
```

I agree that the error you got may be a bit confusing.

A somewhat ugly workaround is `Module[{Subscript}, Subscript[a, 1] = "x"]` or you may try to use the `` Notation` `` package to create symbol names with subscripts in them.  A word of warning though: in some cases, `Module` variables that have `DownValue`s do not get destroyed when the `Module` finishes evaluating.  For more information, see the end of the Module section in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/569/12) by Leonid Shifrin, and the comments on that answer.

Comment: You probably meant `Module[{a}, Subscript[a, 1] = "x"]` in place of `Module[{Subscript}, Subscript[a, 1] = "x"]`?

Comment: @Leonid No, I meant what I wrote, and I agree that it is a hack.  But it allows both displaying subscripted variables as such, localization, and usage in a Manipulate.  If we write `Module[{a}, Subscript[a, 1] = "x"]`, that'll be leaky.  `Module[{Subscript}, Subscript[a, 1] = "x"]` renames subscript, and won't leak so easily.

Comment: It won't be more leaky (assuming you meant garbage collection), in this case. Referencing symbols in UI components is enough to prevent their collection, since UI components by themselves are global objects (they are expressions interpreted in a certain way by the Front-End).

Comment: @Leonid Yes, I remember when we talked about Temporary symbols with DownValues not always getting collected.  But I think in many use cases these would not need to be referenced.

Comment: Perhaps. +1 either way.

Comment: @Leonid I should link to the post where you explain how Module is leaky, but I can't find it.  Can you help me?

Comment: This was done in the comments to this answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs/569#569. I will soon exctract the pieces of that conversation and add a small section to that answer.

Answer (score 7):

`Module` only works with Symbols.

```
Head[ Subscript[a, 1] ]
```

> ```
> Subscript
> ```

Perhaps you can use [`` Internal`InheritedBlock ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25769/121) or  [`` Internal`LocalizedBlock ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71881/121).

```
Subscript[a, 1] = "x";
Subscript[a, 2] = "y";
foo := Subscript[a, 1]

Internal`InheritedBlock[{Subscript},
  Subscript[a, 1] = "new";
  DownValues[Subscript]
]

Subscript[a, 1]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[a1] :> "new", HoldPattern[a2] :> "y"}
>
> "x"
> ```

Note the different syntax and starting value within each Block:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Subscript},
  DownValues[Subscript]
]

Internal`LocalizedBlock[{Subscript[a, 1]},
  DownValues[Subscript]
]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[a1] :> "x",  HoldPattern[a2] :> "y"}
>
> {HoldPattern[a1] :> System`Private`$Localized, HoldPattern[a2] :> "y"}
> ```

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Subscript},
 Subscript[a, 1] = "x";
 DownValues[Subscript]
]
```

Beware that neither function actually works like `Module`:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Subscript},
 Subscript[a, 1] = "new";
 foo
]

Internal`LocalizedBlock[{Subscript[a, 1]},
 Subscript[a, 1] = "new";
 foo
]
```

> ```
> "new"
>
> "new"
> ```

```
a := "old"
b := a
Module[{a = "new"}, b]
```

> ```
> "old"
> ```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the explanations above you can avoid this by using the `Notations` package. Cut and pasting code would be confusing I think -- things don't seem to paste as I would like them too -- so I'll paste the screen grab

[image]

So now the subscripted variable is recognized as a symbol and the problem goes away.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a mattern of `Module`'s syntax. 
You'll see that the message was generated from `Module` and not from `Set` (=)

**Note**

In fact, `Set` doesn't even seem to be called internally when you run a regular `Module` (even though `Trace` suggests it does)

We disable Set but it still works

```
In[42]:= ClearAll[x, y];
Block[{Set},
 Module[{x = 8},
  y = 9;
  {x, y}
  ]]

Out[43]= {8, y}
```