# Module with "local functions"

Tags: function-construction, variable-definitions, scoping

I am trying to use a `Module` having "local functions", i.e., those which I need to define only inside this module.

So I tried this:

```
norm[p_] := Module[{
  fun1[p_] := p^2 + p - 1;
  fun2[p_] := p^3 - p^2 + p + 1
 },
 Max[fun1[p], fun2[p]]
];
```

The function is compiling, but when I try to evaluate it--say, I try:

```
norm[2]
```

Its giving me an error telling:

> `Module::lvsym`: Local variable specification `{fun1[p_]:=p^2+p-1;fun2[p_]:=p^3-p^2+p+1}` contains `fun1[p_]:=p^2+p-1;fun2[p_]:=p^3-p^2+p+1`, which is not a symbol or an assignment to a symbol

How do we avoid this error? I want to give functions in the space between { ... }.

Comment: That's some determined code formatting. :^)  There is a much easier way:  just select the entire block of code and click the `{ }` button above the edit box to indent your code as a code block.  Also see [editing help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: Yes, or just press `Ctrl+K`

Comment: *Mathematica* is not a compiled language. The absence of messages at any particular point is not a good indication of correctness, since the evaluator assumes that what you're doing is meaningful until it arrives at something that's manifestly not.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You cannot make definitions with patterns on the left-hand side in the first argument of a scoping construct (such as `Module`).  You need do that in the body of the `Module`.  You should also use a different symbol for the internal function parameter.

```
norm[x_] :=
  Module[{fun1, fun2},
    fun1[p_] := p^2 + p - 1;
    fun2[p_] := p^3 - p^2 + p + 1;
    Max[fun1[x], fun2[x]]
  ];
```

Closely related:

- [Subscripts - Why do I see the error "only assignments to symbols are allowed" when using a Module and not otherwise?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/869/121)

Comment: Mr.Wizard I am struggling with understanding module, because in some examples ive see they assign only lists where you have assigned {fun1,fun2}, an other times its functions as you have done above? what is actually  happening. I have read the mathematica guide but when i see all the different examples i get confused.

Comment: @ALEXANDER You should read answers to [(559)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/559/121).  I particularly like [WReach's answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/633/121) as a place to start.  In my own *brief* words `Module` creates local equivalents for the Symbols given in the first argument (`fun1` and `fun2`) above and silently uses these in place of the global versions.  For example you may have `fun1$325` used in place of `fun1` wherever `fun1` appears in the body of the module.  They can be used for both direct assignments (`fun1 = 5`) and pattern definitions (as above).

Comment: If you truly understand a concept you can always explain it in a simple way---> Now it all makes sense! Thank you Mr. Wizard