# Getting mesage: Set::setps assignment is not a symbol

Tags: list-manipulation, assignment

Please, tell me what is the issue with the following code?

```
Dimensions[Subscript[R, 2]]
```

> ```
> {201, 161, 53}
> ```

```
Table[
  If[Subscript[R, 2][[x, y, z]] != 2, Subscript[R, 2 ][[x, y, z]] = 0], 
  {x, 1, 201}, {y, 1, 161}, {z, 1, 53}];
```

I am getting this error:

> Set::setps: Subscript[R, 2] in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/869/187

Answer (score 3):

What you see here is the direct result of [ignoring advice](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/187):

> Don't use subscripted variables if you don't know the concequences!

What happens is that you *think* you assign your array to a variable `R`... you don't! Basic example

```
Subscript[a, 1] = {1, 2, 3}

(* {1, 2, 3} *)
```

Now try `?a` and if this doesn't work, try to find where your list is stored.
Right, it is stored as `DownValues` for `Subscript`:

```
DownValues[Subscript]

(* {HoldPattern[Subscript[a, 1]] :> {1, 2, 3}} *)
```

Unfortunately, the assignment operator for list elements aka

```
l[[n]] = blub
```

does not work here. Therefore, use simple symbols and you are fine.