# Subscripts in variable names: Bug?

Tags: variable-definitions, subscript

In the following plot, one of the two functions

```
{-par, par}
```

defined by

```
par = (2 + 3 Subscript[y, 3] - 
 9 (Subscript[y, 3])^2 + ((1 + 3 Subscript[y, 3])^2 (4 - 
     36 (Subscript[y, 1])^2 - 12 Subscript[y, 3] + 
     9 (Subscript[y, 3])^2))^(1/2))^(1/2)/(3 Sqrt[2]);
```

has an erroneously reduced domain:

```
Plot3D[{-par, par}, {Subscript[y, 3], -(1/3), 2/3}, 
{Subscript[y, 1], -(Subscript[y, 3] - 2/3)/2, 
(Subscript[y, 3] - 2/3)/2}, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

When I replace the variables

```
{ Subscript[y, 1], Subscript[y, 3] }
```

by

```
{ a, b }
```

then the error disappears.

I am using Mathmatica 9 on Mac OS X

Comment: The community wiki here on basic syntax issues http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/1952 links to the canonical (for me) answers to how and why not to use subscripts as variables - http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1005/1952 and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/871/1952

Comment: Thanks. Instructions http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/1952 suggest to use indexed variables like `a[1]` or  `a[2]`. However I get the same domain error in the above plot when I replace `Subscript[y, 1]` by `a[1]` and `Subscript[y, 3]` by `a[2]`. Help? How to use indexed variables in a general situation?

Comment: unfortunately I can't explain why that is still playing up. Hopefully another user will be able to help.