# Plotting 2-D Electron Density Carbon Atoms

Tags: plotting, physics

I need to create a 2-D electron energy density plot in Mathematica to compare with my STM experimental results in my lab class.  This would be done by plotting the sum of the symmetric and anti-symmetric wave functions,

$$\Psi_s(\textbf{r}) = \sum_{i=1}^{3}a_i\cos(\textbf{k}_i\cdot\textbf{r})$$
$$\Psi_a(\textbf{r}) = \sum_{i=1}^{3}b_i\sin(\textbf{k}_i\cdot\textbf{r})$$
and squaring it to get this,
$$\Psi_s^2(\textbf{r})+\Psi_a^2(\textbf{r})=\Big[\sum_{i=1}^{3}a_i\cos(\textbf{k}_i\cdot\textbf{r})\Big]^2+\Big[\sum_{i=1}^{3}b_i\sin(\textbf{k}_i\cdot\textbf{r})\Big]^2$$
Where the k's are equal to,
$$\textbf{k}_1=\frac{4\pi}{3d_b}\hat{y}$$
$$\textbf{k}_2=\frac{4\pi}{3d_b}(-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}\hat{x}-\frac{1}{2}\hat{y})$$
$$\textbf{k}_3=\frac{4\pi}{3d_b}(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}\hat{x}-\frac{1}{2}\hat{y})$$
Here is what I have so far

```
Needs["VectorAnalysis`"]
r = {1, 1, 0};
k1 = 4*Pi/3 (2.46) {0, 1, 0};
k2 = 4*Pi/3 (2.46) {-(Sqrt[3]/2), -(1/2), 0};
k3 = 4*Pi/3 (2.46) {(Sqrt[3]/2), -(1/2), 0};

Subscript[\[Psi], s] = 
Cos[DotProduct[k1, r]]*x + Cos[DotProduct[k2, r]]*x + 
Cos[DotProduct[k3, r]]*x;

Subscript[\[Psi], a] = 
Sin[DotProduct[k1, r]]*y + Sin[DotProduct[k2, r]]*y + 
Sin[DotProduct[k3, r]]*y;
DensityPlot[(Subscript[\[Psi], s] x)^2 + (Subscript[\[Psi], a]
y)^2, {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}]
```

Resulting in this

[image]

However, it should be uniform distribution of "bright spots" to model the electron density of carbon atoms, something along the lines of this

[image]

Could someone help me out with this?  It would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Rosie, and welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor. Thank you for your complete and well-formatted post. I will post a complete answer shortly, but first, please note that you haven't actually specified functions of x and y, and that `Subscript` can get you into trouble. I strongly suggest that you have a look at [the material here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) for some ideas. Also, what version are you using? The `VectorAnalysis` package is obsolete and deprecated.

Comment: @Rosie, do not forget to tick (not only upvote) the answer if it solves your problem =))

Comment: @garej Thanks I will do so

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you define your constants this way, you can write the functions using `Sum` - and looking at your code, it seems that you wanted to define `db=2.46` - if so, then you did not correctly put it in the denominator, it was in the numerator.

```
db = 2.46;
k[1] = 4*Pi/(3 db) {0, 1};
k[2] = 4*Pi/(3 db) {-(Sqrt[3]/2), -(1/2)};
k[3] = 4*Pi/(3 db) {(Sqrt[3]/2), -(1/2)};
a[1] = a[2] = a[3] = 1;
```

Now define the wave functions (this is where you had your problems - you had defined `r` as a constant, which isn't what your functions say)

```
ψs[r_] := Sum[a[i] Cos[(k[i]).r], {i, 3}];
ψa[r_] := Sum[a[i] Sin[(k[i]).r], {i, 3}];
```

And then it isn't clear whether you wanted to plot the square of the sum, $\left(\Psi_s(r)+\Psi_a(r)\right)^2$, or the sum of the squares, $\left(\Psi_s^2(r)+\Psi_a^2(r)^2\right)$.  Only the square of their sum would show quantum interference effects.  Here are both plots:

```
Grid[{{
  DensityPlot[(ψs[{x, y}] + ψa[{x, y}])^2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotPoints -> 100, ImageSize -> 400], 
  DensityPlot[(ψs[{x, y}]^2 + ψa[{x, y}]^2), {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotPoints -> 100, ImageSize -> 400]
  }}]
```

[image: density plots]

**Edit**:  All of the tips given by Verbeia are very important, I didn't add them here so as not to repeat her - I just recognized this was in my area of expertise and added what I could.

Comment: I see, this makes a lot more sense.    When I defined r as {1,1,0}, aren't the cartesian unit vectors x,y,z already built in though when I use the curly brackets? Otherwise thank you, this helped immensely, I'm new with Mathematica so this was very enlightening :)

Comment: Thanks @JasonB - I should point out, though, that I'm a girl :-)  The physics bit is not my area of expertise, so thank you for the complementary answer.

Answer (score 8):

There are several things going on with your existing code. The first tip is that using `Subscript` can cause complications, so people tend to recommend that beginners don't use it for variable names.

The second tip is that the `VectorAnalysis` package is obsolete since version 9, and in any case, the usual `Dot` (`.`) function built into the main system will do what you want.

The third (and more fundamental) issue is that you have not actually defined functions of `x` and `y` for your `DensityPlot` to address. The `x` and `y` used in a plotting function are not the same as the ones you use outside that plot to define the expression to be plotted. This is a scoping issue; I recommend you have a look at [some of the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ScopingConstructs.html) on this issue. You instead need to define a function that takes a parameter, using the `SetDelayed` notation (`:=`). You would, for example, rewrite your first $\psi$ function as:

```
psis[x_] := 
 Cos[DotProduct[k1, r]]*x + Cos[DotProduct[k2, r]]*x + Cos[DotProduct[k3, r]]*x;
```

Or using the built-in `Dot`:

```
psis1[x_] := Cos[k1.r]*x + Cos[k2.r]*x + Cos[k3.r]*x
```

Re-writing the function shows another issue: your functions are linear in `x` and `y` respectively. I think you actually want to rewrite them as follows.

```
psis2[x_] := Cos[k1.r*x] + Cos[k2.r*x] + Cos[k3.r*x]; 
psia2[y_] := Sin[k1.r*y] + Sin[k2.r*y] + Sin[k3.r*y];
```

This becomes obvious when you plot each version (note I've added something to `psis1` because it's otherwise identical to psis):

```
Plot[{psis[x], psis1[x] + 10, 5 psis2[x]}, {x, 0, 100}]
```

[image]

So using these changed versions of your functions, we get closer to what you expect:

```
DensityPlot[(psis2[x])^2 + ( psia2[y])^2, {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}, 
  ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]
```

[image]

It's not quite as in your desired picture, which leads me to suspect that you need to tweak your functional forms a bit more. But as I'm an economist and not a physicist, I'll have to leave that bit to you.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into the resource you provided.  What sort of problems can one encounter by using a subscript to define a variable?

Comment: Hi @Rosie - as noted [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/8), if you see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/871/8), you will see that subscripted symbols are not plain symbols, so you can’t assign values (strictly speaking, [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html)) to them directly