# Plotting an expression with a complex-valued exponential

Tags: plotting, manipulate, complex

Given the wave function $\Psi\left ( x,t \right ) = \psi\left ( x \right )T\left ( t \right )$ with the spatial component of the wavefunction 
$\psi(x) = \psi_{0}e^{-ikx}$, I tried

```
Manipulate[Plot[B Exp[-I k x], {x, 0, 10}], {B, -10, 10}, {k, 0, 10}]
```

which gives

[image: not giving me what I'm looking for]

That is not what I'm looking for. Trying

```
Plot[E^(-I x), {x, 0, 10}]
```

gives

[image: weird]

which I find just plain weird.

Am I using the wrong function or is this an inherent 'user' problem?

How do I get the right plot? In any case, I'm trying to plot the left moving wave of the spatial component of the Schrödinger's equation. I do not know how it looks like but, intuitively, it ought to resembles decays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wave function has real and imaginary parts, so can plot them separately,

```
wf[x_] := E^(-I x);
Plot[{Re[wf[x]], Im[wf[x]]}, {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Re Ψ", "Im Ψ"}]
```

[image]

Comment: The link you provided looks promising. Possible to leave your post as it is? Would like to understand the codes and extrapolate.

Comment: Definitely - I like to answer when possible even while marking as a duplicate (I feed off the imaginary internet points I get when you click the check mark next to my answer).  I can post the code for the `Manipulate` but you can probably figure that out.

Comment: @Physkid, just plotting a wave function like this isn't too interesting, the cool stuff happens when you have superpositions and interference effects.  See [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/95810/9490) post for an example of interference effects in plots.

Comment: Definitely speaking to a computational physicists on the other end of the screen.
Yes, a plot like the above isn't interests. I will be catching up on the links.