# How to implement the for loop to replace text strings or texts?

Tags: functions, programming, string-manipulation, variable-definitions

I wonder define a bunch variables named like $X_1$, $X_2$, $...$, $X_n$. Is there some smart way to declare them instead of by pure typing. One trick I can image is to use the **for loop**,`For [i = 1, i <= n, i++]`, to replace the subindices,. However, now each `i` is not numbers but texts, I don't know how to implement the **for loop** to texts or text strings. Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: Please avoid using subscripts. Some feferences: [ref1](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1004/193), [ref2](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/869/193), [ref3](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/193)

Answer (score 3):

This would be more idiomatic to Mathematica than using a for loop:

```
indices = {"a", "b", "c"};

Array[(x[indices[[#]]] = #) &, 3];

{x["a"], x["b"], x["c"]}
```

> {1, 2, 3}

This is an equivalent for loop:

```
For[i = 1, i <= Length[indices], i++,
 x[indices[[i]]] = i]
```

Comment: I'd have used `Scan[]` myself…

Comment: @J.M. -- Can you elaborate for the sake of posterity?

Comment: @Jagra `Scan[(x[#] = #) &, indices]`