# 3D plot of multiple functions

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

I am just starting to learn Mathematica. I defined two functions

```
Subscript[x, 1][t_, α_] :=1/2 (3 - 2 E^-t + E^t (2 + t) (-1 + α) - α)
```

And

```
Subscript[x, 2][t_, α_] :=1 - 2 E^-t - E^t (2 + t) (-1 + α) + α
```

I ploted the followings

```
Plot[{Subscript[x, 1][t, 0], Subscript[x, 2][t, 0]}, {t, 0, 8}]
Plot[{Subscript[x, 1][5, α], 
  Subscript[x, 2][5, α]}, {α, 0, 1}]
```

My problem is that I want these two plots in 3D plot such that graphics of `x1(t,0)` and `x2(t,0)` are on the xy-plane and graphs of `x1(2,alpha)` and `x2(2,alpha)` lie on them forming a triangular shape in 3D.
Sorry for my english I hope I could explain myself....

Comment: What do you mean by "lie on them"? Do you want to plot the curves of your function inside a plot with axes `t`,`α` and `x`? If so, take a look at [`ParametricPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html)

Comment: `Plot3D[{Subscript[x, 1][t, \[Alpha]], 
  Subscript[x, 2][t, \[Alpha]]}, {t, 0, 2}, {\[Alpha], 0, 1}, 
 ClippingStyle -> None]`

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I added a sketch to explain myself better.

Comment: There's been so many questions with `Subscript` definitions lately. I have an urge to close them all, referring askers to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/26956), [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1004/26956), [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/871/26956), and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18562/26956).

Comment: I edited the image link back into the post, since you had a reference to it.  I assumed it was mistakenly removed.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps this can be motivating:

```
f[t_] := {t, 1/2 (3 - 2 E^(-t) + E^t (2 + t) ), 0}
g[t_] := {t, 1 - 2 E^-t - E^t (2 + t), 0}
h[a_, n_] := 
 Table[Line[{f[j], Mean[{f[j], g[j]}] + {0, 0, a}, g[j]}], {j, 0, 1, 
   1/(n - 1)}]
Manipulate[
 Show[ParametricPlot3D[{f[u], g[u]}, {u, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}], Graphics3D[{Orange, h[a, n]}], 
  BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 1}], {a, 0.1, 1}, {n, Range[3, 10]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, ıt is almost what I need but the important point is the left side of the triangle must be the graph of the function x1(5, alpha) and the right side is the graph of the function x2(5, alpha).

Comment: @bluehills as I alluded to...I suggest you adapt/correct or try your own newer approach...I find it is the best way to learn MMA and hopefully achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a 2-parameter `ParametricPlot3D` with options `MeshFunctions` and `Mesh`. Using the examples from ubpdqn's answer:

```
ClearAll[f, g]
f[t_] := 1/2 (3 - 2 E^(-t) + E^t (2 + t))
g[t_] := 1 - 2 E^-t - E^t (2 + t)
a = .5; m = 8;
ParametricPlot3D[{{u, v g[u] + (1 - v) (f[u] + g[u])/2, (1 - v) a},
  {u, (1 - v) f[u] + v (f[u] + g[u])/2, v a}},  {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
 BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-10, 10}, {-1, 1}},
 MeshFunctions -> {# &, #3 &, #5 &, ConditionalExpression[#3, #5 > .5] &}, 
 Mesh -> {m, {a}, {0}, {0.001}}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Orange, Dashed], 
 MeshStyle -> {Directive[Orange, Dashed], Directive[Thick, Green], 
   Directive[Thick, Red], Directive[Thick, Blue]}, 
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[.1]]
```

[image]