# How to make subscripts from list?

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

I want to make list of subscripted symbols in functional way. So that given edges list I can get something like the list below/

```
edges = {1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 
     2 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 5 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 5 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 
     6 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 4}
{Subscript[x, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3], Subscript[x, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 5], Subscript[x, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 1], Subscript[x,
  2 \[DirectedEdge] 6], Subscript[x, 
 5 \[DirectedEdge] 2], Subscript[x, 5 \[DirectedEdge] 6], Subscript[x,
  6 \[DirectedEdge] 1], Subscript[x, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 4]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found solution by myself.

```
Subscript[x, #] & /@ edges
```

My mistake was that I tried

```
Subscript[x, #&]  /@ edges
```

Comment: Nice job figuring that out.

Comment: Indeed, good job. And welcome on Mathematica.StackExchange! Just a hint: Try to avoid `Subscript` (except only for display). Internally, it works differently than you would expect and leads to lots of undesired behavior. Just search for `Subscript` on this site and you will find a plethoria of these issues. See also [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1004/can-we-use-letter-with-a-subscript-as-a-variable-in-mathematica/1005#1005) or [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/869/subscripts-why-do-i-see-the-error-only-assignments-to-symbols-are-allowed-wh/871#871)